# refactor NodeJs functions

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a big `app.js` file and want to split the code. I took all my routes into a module called `routes.js`

```
module.exports = function(app){

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.redirect('/page1');
});

app.get('/page1', function (req, res) {
  res.render('page1');
});

app.get('/page2/:id', function (req, res) {
    res.render('page2', {
      val: Number(req.params.id)
    });
});

}
```

and in my app.js I call

```
const routes = require('./Server/routes')(app);
```

So this works fine.

I have some functions like

```
function loadData(id, callback) {
  fs.readFile('./database.json', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
    var json = JSON.parse(data);
    var arr = json.arr;
    var obj = arr.find(e => e.id === Number(id));
    callback(obj);
  });
}
```

and want to have them in separate files too. How can I do this? I am able to export one function but how can I export more than one?

Like

```
module.exports = function(){

function sayHello(){
   console.log("Hello");
}

function calc(){
   return 5 + 7;
}

}
```

require the module and call

```
myModule.sayHello();

var num = myModule.calc();
```

Comment: Here you [go](https://gist.github.com/oneturkmen/cf0cddeb80e10c415c8ab89d2c577293). Let me know if this is what you asked for.

Comment: I think so, is this correct? https://hastebin.com/unobutifem.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your new module you can export an object and define your functions inside object

```
module.export = {
    sayHello: function() {
        console.log("Hello");
    },
    calc: function() {
        return 5 + 7;
    }
}

// usage: const mymodule = require('path/to/your/file');
```

also you can export a function and define your needed functions in prototype

```
function mymodule(someArgsIfNeeded) {
    // do some initialization
}

mymodule.prototype.sayHello = function() {
    console.log("Hello");
}
mymodule.prototype.calc = function() {
    return 5 + 7;
}

module.export = mymodule

// usage: const mymodule = require('path/to/your/file')(someArgsIfNeeded);
```

Comment: ah okay, this syntax is new to me